# Open a file, and print out a line with a particular number in C?

Tags: c, fopen

I know it is a very basic thing, but I'm not very good at file handling in C.

I'm writing a custom error handler for something, and it needs to open a file, find a line by its number, and save it in a **char***.

Can someone suggest a way to do it?

Edit: **What am I doing wrong?** Sometimes it gets the right line, but sometimes it misses:

```
if (file_available)
            {
                char str_buf[81];
                int counter = 0;
                FILE *fp;
                fp=fopen(error_filename, "r");
                while (error_lineno != counter)
                {
                    fgets(str_buf, 81, fp);
                    counter += 1;
                }

                php_printf(html_formats[5],"Line",str_buf);
                fclose(fp);
            }
```

Comment: How can you store a 2 digit line number in a char?

Comment: I want to save the line itself, not its number.

Comment: I deleted my answer, because I realized you were asking something else.  For the record, based on the comment he left I believe what Nick wants to accomplish is to read a line of PHP source code based on an error message containing the line number.

Comment: @Alpine Even signed chars go up to 127... 3 digits on the other hand might be tricky...

Comment: Everything looks fine to me, except for the fact that you have no way of knowing a priori what the longest line will be, and therefore you will always have to worry about a line length being greater than whatever char buffer size you allocate as your code is written now. In this case, I would guess that there are lines greater than 80 characters. If you want to remove this possibility and still use `fgets`, you'll have to check if the last character before the NULL is a newline and not increment the counter if it's not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to the GNU C library, you can use [`getline`](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Line-Input.html):

```
FILE *f;
char *line = NULL;
size_t line_size = 0;
int i=0;

/* Open the file, or get access it to it however you will */

for(; i <= requestedLine; ++i) {
    if ( getline(&line, &line_size, f) == -1 ) {
        //error condition, log / bail
    }
}

/* line now holds the line number you want, do whatever you want with it */

fclose(f);
if (line) {
    /* guard against the empty file case */
    free(line);
}
```

`getline` will grab the full line for you and take care of most of the memory allocation issues. The first parameters is a pointer to a `char*` buffer (as in a `char**` -- a pointer to a pointer to the beginning `char` of a buffer), and the second is the size of that buffer. If the buffer is not large enough, `getline` will create a new buffer large enough to hold the line and clean up your old one (performs a `realloc`). When the function returns, the first parameter will now point to the new buffer which contains the line, and the second parameter will also be updated to hold the new size of the buffer. The third parameter is simply the `FILE*` object to read from. `getline` will return a -1 on failure, which is why we log / bail in that case.

Note that when all is done you still need to free the buffer that `getline` creates.

Answer (score 2):

You could write a loop with `fgets()` to read lines until you get to the one you want:

```
inputFile = fopen(filename, "r");
while (whichLine--)
{
    fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, inputFile);
}
fclose(inputFile);
```

Add error handling and further details to your taste.

Comment: Can you make it more detailed? I don't know how to handle files at all.

Comment: @Nick Brooks, I added example `fopen()` and `fclose()` lines - hopefully that clears up some of the details for you.

Comment: Actually there are situations where this function fails, most of them depending on the size you assign for the buffer. Lets say you choose a buffer with 100 bytes. Then if you have a line with 120 characters, this function won't properly count the lines in the file.

Comment: @Tiago: correct, and it also doesn't handle a file that is shorter than the line count very gracefully.  That's the 'error handling and further details' left as an exercise for the questioner.

Comment: I don't think I'm doing it right ... http://pastie.org/1586968 . What's wrong with it?

Comment: @Nick Brooks, that code looks fine, with some caveats about error handing and the format of the input file.